# Simulate Launch Options

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, debugging, launching-application

in my `appDelegate`, I have some specifications when the App is launch with a File from  i.e. Mail app.

When I launch my App, everything works normal. When I launch the App via File from Mail, the App crashes. Unfortunately, I am not able to debug it as I can't simulate `launchingOptions`. at the moment, I build and run, then disconnect the iPad, close my App and then go to mail etc … Is there a way to debug?

**Appdelegate.m**

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];

IntroViewController *introViewController = (IntroViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

if (url !=nil) {
    if ([url isFileURL]) {
        introViewController.fileUrl = url;
    }


}

NSLog(@"%@",[url path]);

return YES;
}
```

**IntroViewController**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    if (fileUrl != nil) {
        IntroTableViewController* introTable = (IntroTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;            
        introTable.openedByURL = [fileUrl path];

        TabBarController* tabBarController = (TabBarController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        TargetLSController* targetViewController = (TargetLSController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *urlPath = [fileUrl path];
        targetViewController.currentFilePath = urlPath;
        NSLog(@"%@",urlPath);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Launch" sender:self]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",fileUrl);
}
```

Comment: Can't you still see the console in the Organiser window for that device?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean …

Comment: I meant you can see what NSLog is outputting from Window->Organiser. However, @fichek's answer is _much_ better than my idea :)

Comment: I didnt even know that there was an organizer section where you can see the logs! Thx!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Guessing you use Xcode 4.x)

`Product -> Edit Scheme...` and under `Run <appname>.app` there is `Launch` option in first tab (`Info`). Select `Wait for <appname.app>` to launch`. Now when you perform build & run (or just run), debugger will wait for you to launch the app manually.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Unfortunately, no NSLog is fired anymore?

Comment: You might still be able to see the output from NSLog in the Mac OS X Console.app. Alternatively, if you are running on a device, you might be able to see it in Organizer >> Devices, plug in a device, then select it's Console.