# Time Profiler - Wait for app launch

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments, profiler

When launching my app from a custom URL scheme, when app is not backgrounded, the launch sequence is taking longer then I would like.  I want to use time profiler to see what methods are taking so long.  I know on run there is an option for "Wait for App Launch" so I can launch it using the URL, but I don't see that under the profiling scheme.  Does anyone know a way that I can launch the app fresh, using the URL, and have time profiler running on launch?

Comment: This approach might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725625/simulate-launch-options
You can edit the scheme to wait for you to launch the app before attaching the debugger to the process.

Answer (score -1):

> "see what methods are taking so long"

Do you suppose some method (or a few) are sopping up a lot of CPU time in themselves or by calling other methods that do?
If so, it will be easy to fix, but it's Not Likely.

More likely the time is spent in I/O of one sort or another, and you need to figure out *why*, not *where*.

If you're able to start it under a debugger (say by using @ChrisTruman's recommendation), then all you need to do is interrupt it with Ctrl-C, Ctrl-Break, Escape, or whatever key combination interrupts it.
Do this during the time when, subjectively, it is slow.

Let's suppose the startup is taking three times longer than you think it should.
If that's so, that means two thirds of the time is spent doing the unnecessary I/O or whatever it is.
That means each time you interrupt it, the probability is 2/3 that you will catch it in the act of doing whatever causes the slowness.
So interrupt it a few times, and each time just read the stack, look at variables, etc.
You will see *why* it's being slow.
Don't even look for *where* - that will appear by itself.

That's the basic idea behind [*this technique*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).